# how to replicate parts of code in python into C to execution faster?

Tags: python

i have prepared a project in python language ie a TEXT TO SPEECH synthesizer. Which took a total on 1500 lines of code.
But there few parts of code due to which it is taking so much time to run the code, i want to replace that parts of code in C/c++ lang so that it runs faster.

So i want to know how can i run these parts of code in C++ or improve its speed in any other way??

please suggest,

Answer (score 5):

You could write them in [Cython](http://cython.org/), it's pretty easy.

Alternatively, you can try using numpy, which is already written in C and may have most of the operations you need.

Comment: is it that i just need to write the code in cython nd import that module into the original code??

Comment: Yes, but you also need to compile it, see http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

As Radomir mentioned, Cython might be a good choice: it's essentially a restricted Python with type declarations, automatically translated into C then compiled for execution.

If you want to use pure C, you can write a Python extension module using the Python C API.  This is a good way to go if you need to manipulate Python data structures in your C code.  Using the Python C API, you write in C, but with full access to the Python types and methods.

Or, you can write a pure C dll, then invoke it with `ctypes`.  This is a good choice if you don't need any access to Python data structures in your C code.  With this technique, your C code only deals with C types, and your Python code has to understand how to use ctypes to get at that C data.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [Python extension module](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) in C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try effect of [psyco module](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) to your code's running time (Python 2.6 or earlier) or [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) (python JIT written in subset python). There is also C++ compiler [shedskin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/), Windows is not supported in latest versions though.